# Doctrine 2 orm:schema-tool:create giving Runtime Exception: Too many arguments

Tags: php, doctrine

i am trying out the Doctrine 2 sandbox. downloaded the main Doctrine 2 ORM from http://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2 the `dbal` from http://github.com/doctrine/dbal and `common` from `http://github.com/doctrine/common`. placed the packages in approparate folders ...

```
D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\Doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM
D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\Doctrine\lib\vendor\doctrine-common\lib\Doctrine\Common
D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\Doctrine\lib\vendor\doctrine-dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL
```

from the sandbox folder i tried to get the version to see if everything works ok ...

```
D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\Doctrine\tools\sandbox>php doctrine.php -V
Doctrine Command Line Interface version 2.0.0BETA4-DEV
```

looks ok.

```
D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\Doctrine\tools\sandbox>php doctrine.php orm:schema-tool:create ./Entities

  [RuntimeException]
  Too many arguments.

orm:schema-tool:create [--dump-sql] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|--verbose] [-V|--version] [-c|--color] [-n|--no-interaction] command
```

then fails ...

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known problem with the tutorial.  Try removing the ./Entities argument as suggested in the bug report: 
http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DWEB-53?page=com.atlassian.jira.ext.fisheye%3Afisheye-issuepanel.

Answer (score 0):

Do:

`php doctrine.php orm:schema-tool:create --dump-sql`

---

For a running example of the Cookbook code that can be downloaded, see [here](http://phphints.wordpress.com/2010/11/11/doctrine-2-orm-cookbook-example/).